# Minipage: How to change the size of graphic and table

Tags: tables, graphics, minipage

how do you change the size of the graphic and still have the caption centered below the graphic? How do you prevent the table to be printed like in the code below when having long words in the table? How to center the whole minipages-package?

Caption of graphic not centered. Long words in table:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{spie} 

\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{figure}[ht] 
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth} 
   \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image.pdf} 
   \caption{Diese caption soll unter das Bild.} 
   \label{fig:Bild} 
\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth} 
  \centering 
  \captionof{table}{Diese caption soll über die Tabelle.} 
  \label{tab:Tabelle} 
  \begin{tabular}{ll} 
    \toprule 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Versuchsparameter}}\\       
\midrule 
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 1 & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\ 
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB 2 & 2\\ 
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC 3 & 3\\ 
\bottomrule 
  \end{tabular} 
\end{minipage} 
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Looks okay, but package is not centered:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{spie} 

\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{figure}[ht] 
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth} 
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image.pdf} 
   \caption{Diese caption soll unter das Bild.} 
   \label{fig:Bild} 
\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth} 
  \centering 
  \captionof{table}{Diese caption soll über die Tabelle.} 
  \label{tab:Tabelle} 
  \begin{tabular}{ll} 
    \toprule 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Versuchsparameter}}\\       
\midrule 
Parameter 1 & 1\\ 
Parameter 2 & 2\\ 
Parameter 3 & 3\\ 
\bottomrule 
  \end{tabular} 
\end{minipage} 
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this:

[image]

?

with use of `tabularx` you can determine table width in advance:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{spie}

\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[tableposition=top,skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{minipage}{.48\linewidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image.pdf}
   \caption{Diese caption soll unter das Bild.}
   \label{fig:Bild}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.48\linewidth}
  \centering
  \captionof{table}{Diese caption soll über die Tabelle.}
  \label{tab:Tabelle}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Versuchsparameter}}\\
\midrule
Parameter 1 & 1\\
Parameter 2 & 2\\
Parameter 3 & some long long long long long long text\\
\bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```